# NPSP did not create an account

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact, npsp

Good day everyone,

I am installing an NPSP package. After I've set up the NPSP settings, I've try to import a contact by batch. The problem is that, there is no account created after I created a contact.But when I try to individually update a contact, it will create an account. I am using household model. What are the possible thing that I am missing? Please help.

Thank you...

Comment: Do you have any customizations, custom code, etc or is this a clean install of the NPSP in a clean org? if a clean install someone with some NPSP knowledge could possibly help otherwise I am afraid that there are too many possibilities to give a concise answer

Answer (score 5):

When you import contacts that are donors into the NPSP, there's a `NPSP Data Import Object` that you want to import them into first after which you can run the [Nonprofit Starter Pack Data Importer Tool](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Administrators-Guide-to-Importing-Donor-Data) which will create the accounts and households for you if it can't match them up to existing data.

For more on this I highly recommend you visit [Import Data into Salesforce](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Import-Data-NPSP?popup=false&navBack=H4sIAAAAAAAAAIuuVipWslLyzssvz0lNSU_1yM9NVdJRygaKFSSmp4ZkluSA-KVAvn58aaZ-NkyhPpCDosu-ODWxKDnDNjO3IL-oRLsALFGsXZ5ZkqFdkFiZm5pXUqxUGwsADNRhrnEAAAA) which has links to all the docs and a video on importing data into the NPSP. There's a template you want to use and other things you'll want to do. If you're not familiar with the NPSP, I also highly recommend you go through the two trailhead modules in the [Manage Fundraising for NonProfits Trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trail/nonprofit_fundraising).

In general, your best resource for NPSP questions is [The Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/publogin). You need to be a registered User in an NPSP Org to access it.

**EDIT**

NPSP updates itself automatically on a regular basis. If you check, you should be at least at ver 3.7 or above right now (not certain what release they're on see [Which Version of Nonprofit Starter Pack Am I Using?](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Which-Version-of-Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-Am-I-Using)). Apps like Appsona which are free to non-profits are best suited to importing data directly as they know how to handle this kind of data directly. It's possible you may have one of the triggers turned off or something like that. More than anything, the key thing for many orgs will be they `type` of contact that's specified. If you click on the button that opens all of your Apps, you'll find a NPSP Setup Tab where all of the NPSP configuration settings are contained. There [Nonprofit Starter Pack 3 Documentation](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-3-Documentation) will explain all of the settings and how to configure them particularly [Manage Households, Organizations, Contacts, and Addresses](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-3-Documentation#households).

Some orgs may have volunteers that aren't `donors`. When that happens, an account may not be created for them, just a contact. Also, when an org has Corporate Sponsors or "Partners", they may have "related contacts" that don't fall under the household model, but instead are a child of the account for that Sponsor. It all depends on how your Org is configured. Those contacts would need to be configured to have that record type or be related to that particular account when imported.

The documents I referenced should help explain most of those things. This kind of missing information would also explain why it occurs intermittently for you. Again, I'd encourage you to get involved in the Power of Us Hub where you'll find a great community of very helpful and friendly people who are much more knowledgeable about these issues. I've stood up a number of smaller nonprofit orgs, plus done some pro-bono work, so only have a limited knowledge of all the NPSP pack's features compared to the pro's who are on the Hub.

Comment: Thank you so much ++. I already use npsp before but this just happen recently that there is no account created when I created a contact.  Also it didn't happen all the time. I am thinking that maybe there are some settings that was updated in NPSP when it happens but I am not sure.

Comment: See my edited answer which I hope addressed the remainder of your questions. If this post leads you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: @crmprogdev - Thank you for this answer. For those of us that do not use the NPSP it helps shed light on some of the things to consider around the NPSP. This answer I believe is more valuable than to just this question. Wonder if it can be made a WIKI around the NPSP?

Comment: @Eric. Pleased you found it helpful. I do a lot in Dallas with nonprofits including organizing Dallas GiveForce right now. The NPSP is a very different "animal" which uses a totally different paradigm that's opposite to what a regular SF Org uses of Account first, Contact next. It's challenging to train a Dev to work with it when we do stand-ups if they don't go thru Trailhead. Using the template and import object is essential for success when setting up an org. The tools we normally rely on don't directly suit the task.